# fpdf : when using multicell for wrapping text, how to get proper align?

Tags: php, fpdf

it seems i got 2 spaces between line after wrapping text with multicell,

how to make it properly? i want to change it to 1 space ..

i have no clue even with google

```
$this->CI->fpdf->MultiCell(75,10,'Lorem Ipsum adalah contoh teks atau dummy dalam industri percetakan dan penataan huruf atau typesetting. Lorem Ipsum telah menjadi standar contoh teks sejak tahun 1500an, saat seorang tukang cetak yang tidak dikenal mengambil sebuah kumpulan teks dan mengacaknya untuk menjadi sebuah buku contoh huruf.',0,'J');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height parameter lower, f.e.:

```
$this->CI->fpdf->MultiCell(75,5,'Lorem Ipsum adalah contoh teks atau dummy dalam industri percetakan dan penataan huruf atau typesetting. Lorem Ipsum telah menjadi standar contoh teks sejak tahun 1500an, saat seorang tukang cetak yang tidak dikenal mengambil sebuah kumpulan teks dan mengacaknya untuk menjadi sebuah buku contoh huruf.',0,'J');
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in MultiCell method is the height of each line(Cell) you can set a fixed value or use the actual font height;

```
$fontSize=$this->CI->fpdf->FontSize;
$this->CI->fpdf->MultiCell(75,$fontSize,'Lorem Ipsum adalah contoh teks atau dummy dalam industri percetakan dan penataan huruf atau typesetting. Lorem Ipsum telah menjadi standar contoh teks sejak tahun 1500an, saat seorang tukang cetak yang tidak dikenal mengambil sebuah kumpulan teks dan mengacaknya untuk menjadi sebuah buku contoh huruf.',0,'J');
```